# When loading and writing a PNG image to PDF using Pillow (PIL), how do I fix the size of the image in the PDF?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am reading in a list of PNG images from a directory and I want to maintain the image sizes.

However, when I go to save them, each image is automatically resized to fit the entire page AND it automatically rotates the images to landscape rather than keeping them portrait.

Example of what I am doing below:

```
from PIL import Image

x = []

# get list of images
for i in [list of image files in my directory]:
    im = Image.open(i)
    im = im.convert('RGB') # will not save as RGBA
    x.append(im)

im.save('my_doc.pdf', save_all=True, append_images=x)
```

Yet, the images which are all the same dimensions and sized to fit neatly onto a single page in portrait orientation, are being rotated to landscape orientation and stretched to the limits of the page making them blurry as a result.

I want one image per page, using the native dimensions of the images, and in portrait.

Is there a way to prevent PIL from doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you can currently control via keyword arguments is [documented](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#pdf). For **resolution** it says: "Image resolution in DPI. This, together with the number of pixels in the image, will determine the physical dimensions of the page that will be saved in the PDF."

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I will give this a try.